# Android WSDL Web Service ksoap2

Tags: android, service, wsdl, web, ksoap

I am trying to connect to a web service via an Android device by using the ksoap2 library.  I've gotten it to work on two different services fine, but now I've ran into a problem.  Whenever I pass an object instead of a primitive type it gives me an error.  I've implemented the classes using KvmSerializable and still no luck.  Here is the xml of the request sent from a web browser that works, and the xml of the request sent from the Android device that doesn't work. Any suggestions at all would be great!

Browser

```
     <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <CreateTour xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <SecurityKey>2b9fac80-97ce-4483-b9e8-c1816656e1db</SecurityKey>
        <OriginDetails xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <d4p1:Creator>3</d4p1:Creator>
            <d4p1:CreatorOS>1</d4p1:CreatorOS>
            <d4p1:CreatorVersion>1.0.0.18191</d4p1:CreatorVersion>
            <d4p1:IP>192.168.1.61</d4p1:IP>
            <d4p1:UserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7</d4p1:UserAgent>
        </OriginDetails>
        <Details xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <d4p1:Baths>1.00</d4p1:Baths>
            <d4p1:Beds>6</d4p1:Beds>
            <d4p1:City>Knoxville</d4p1:City>
            <d4p1:Country>US</d4p1:Country>
            <d4p1:CreatedDate>2012-01-24T17:50:09.0541149-05:00</d4p1:CreatedDate>
            <d4p1:Description>Another test</d4p1:Description>
            <d4p1:Garage>9</d4p1:Garage>
            <d4p1:MLSID>400</d4p1:MLSID>
            <d4p1:ModifiedDate>2012-01-24T17:50:09.0541149-05:00</d4p1:ModifiedDate>
            <d4p1:MusicFile>/music/magic.mp3</d4p1:MusicFile>
            <d4p1:Price>400</d4p1:Price>
            <d4p1:PropertyType>0</d4p1:PropertyType>
            <d4p1:SF>400</d4p1:SF>
            <d4p1:Schools i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:ShowAddress>true</d4p1:ShowAddress>
            <d4p1:ShowPrice>true</d4p1:ShowPrice>
            <d4p1:State>TN</d4p1:State>
            <d4p1:Status i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:Street>9111 Cross Park Drive</d4p1:Street>
            <d4p1:Title>Test</d4p1:Title>
            <d4p1:TourID i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:YearBuilt i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:Zip>37923</d4p1:Zip>
        </Details>
    </CreateTour>
</s:Body>
```

Android

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
    <CreateTour xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
        <SecurityKey i:type="d:string">641c38a3-b290-45db-b2d4-8c4edac5934a</SecurityKey>
        <OriginDetails i:type="d:anyType">
            <Creator i:type="d:int">4</Creator>
            <CreatorOS i:type="d:int">6</CreatorOS>
            <CreatorVersion i:type="d:string">1.0</CreatorVersion>
            <IP i:type="d:string">192.168.1.222</IP>
            <UserAgent i:type="d:string"></UserAgent>
        </OriginDetails>
        <Details i:type="d:anyType">
            <Baths i:type="d:int">1</Baths>
            <Beds i:type="d:int">2</Beds>
            <City i:type="d:string">Cleveland</City>
            <Country i:type="d:string">US</Country>
            <CreatedDate i:type="d:string"></CreatedDate>
            <Description i:type="d:string"></Description>
            <Garage i:type="d:int">2</Garage>
            <MLSID i:type="d:string">44</MLSID>
            <ModifiedDate i:type="d:string"></ModifiedDate
            ><MusicFile i:type="d:string"></MusicFile>
            <Price i:type="d:int">400</Price>
            <PropertyType i:type="d:int">0</PropertyType>
            <SF i:type="d:int">777</SF>
            <Schools i:type="d:string"></Schools>
            <ShowAddress i:type="d:boolean">true</ShowAddress>
            <ShowPrice i:type="d:boolean">true</ShowPrice>
            <State i:type="d:string">TN</State>
            <Status i:type="d:int">0</Status>
            <Street i:type="d:string">200 Post Road</Street>
            <Title i:type="d:string">Android Test Tour</Title>
            <TourID i:type="d:int">0</TourID>
            <YearBuilt i:type="d:int">0</YearBuilt>
            <Zip i:type="d:string">37362</Zip>
        </Details>          
    </CreateTour>
</v:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems in the past. I'll give you an example of a part i had to fix in my application and how i did, check if you did these steps in your case:
In the wsdl there was:

```
<message name="invokeService">
     <part name="serviceName" type="xsd:string"/>
     <part name="documents" type="tns:uriList"/>
     <part name="literalDocs" type="ns1:stringArray"/>
     <part name="connID" type="xsd:long"/>
     <part name="gateParams" type="tns:gateRuntimeParameterArray"/>
     <part name="userCtx" type="tns:userContext"/>
</message>
```

So I had to follow these steps:
1- check if your classes implementing KvmSerializable are accurately defined and not missing anything (this is cruciale for complex types)

2-Add ALL the necessary soap object properties that you need, for example in my case :

```
//for the part: <part name="serviceName" type="xsd:string"/>
SoapObject.addProperty("serviceName", whateverServiceNameItWas);

//for the part: <part name="documents" type="tns:uriList"/>,where uriList was a complex type
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("documents");
pi.setValue(usrOptPr.getDocuments());
pi.setType(UriList.class);
sobj.addProperty(pi);
```

**etc...**
3-Build the enveloppe:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(SoapObject);
```

4- Add mappings between complex types(ie local class that implement kvmserializable, and the real matching classes on the web service)

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MAPPINGS:
// A mapping tells the ksoap what class to generate.
// Complex data types that are not mapped are generated as SoapObjects.
// The mapping is required for both the request and the response.
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//for example the UriList above     
soapEnvelope.addMapping(theNamespace, UriList.class.getSimpleName(), UriList.class);
```

5- Add marshalling:(Marshalling uses java serialization to change Objects to stream of data to be unmarshalled on the web service.)

```
Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
floatMarshal.register(soapEnvelope);
```

6- Use AndroidHttpTransport to call the web service 
**UPDATE**
I also noticed that you have in the browser request:

```
<d4p1:Schools i:nil="true" />
```

While in Android:

```
<Schools i:type="d:string"></Schools>
```

Sometimes ksoap2 bugs with such a scenario, i had the same case so what i did is i just removed (commented out, since it allows nil ie null values) this param (ie schools) from its specific class that implements kvmserializable ( of course you will have to modify other stuff in the class like "getPropertyCount" and "getPropertyInfo" to adapt to this change). When i did that it worked, so try that and let me know.

Comment: It actually turned out to be a namespace issue.  Once we changed it on the web service to remove the d4p1 from the child elements it worked fine. Thank you!